# How to write loop to iterate data on AJAX success and bind data to textbox using coffee script in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

Currently the below code gives the data on success.

How do I iterate the data which is in an array and process it to string and bind that to text box.

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'click', '#ListButton', (evt) ->
    console.log("ListButton")
    isvalid = if $("#ListButtonVlaue").val() 
    if isvalid
      $.ajax 'show',
      type: 'POST'
      dataType: 'json'
      data: {
        isvalid: isvalid
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) -> 
        console.log("OK!")
```

If I try to get the length of data which is giving the value of `data: {isvalid: isvalid }` but not on the data in success.

Comment: Can you specify what you are getting in data after ajax success

Comment: in success check `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: In my current code, i do have a variable data and in the success also I have the same. So, when trying to get the length it is giving the upper one. Updated my success data variable name and was able to get the correct value.

Comment: for loop, i have written this code sarr = sarr + ";" +data1[i].name for i in [0...data1.length-1]

Answer (score 0):

Try to render the form as a response. Then with the help of `append` or `replaceWith` replace the existing data.
`append` will add the content within the selector. `replaceWith` replace the content where the selector is present.

```
$("SELECTOR").append(YOUR_RESPONSE);
```

or

```
$("SELECTOR").replaceWith(YOUR_RESPONSE);
```